# How to test AWS integration services flow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, integration-testing, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I got the following flow:

- Put file to S3
- Triggered Lambda function
- DynamoDB table

Due to this flow, I created an integration test which first put a file to S3.

After that, I checked the record over the DynamoDB table which been updated by the Lambda function.

The problem occures when I'm searching for my record, actually I couldn't find it because there is some time interval that I need to wait for the table to be updated. In the second run I was able to see the record from the previous test run.

My question is how can I make this integration test? How can I check for the updated table records after which needs to be inserted after some time using the lambda trigger call.

What I tried so far:

- Use Promise
- Use setTimeout()

These weren't good enough for me, Please advice some better approach.

**My code:**

```
it('Writing single record to DynamoDB - when data is valid JSON and updating the DB is Succeed',
    function(done) {

        var putObjectParams = {
            Bucket: BUCKET,
            Key: FILE_KEY,
            Body: 'some file content'
        };

        s3.putObject(putObjectParams, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err, err.stack);
            } else {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        });


        var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
        var queryParams = {

            TableName: ENV + "-WFMHistoricalUnprocessedFiles",
            ProjectionExpression: "filePath, ingressTime, dir, fileName",
            KeyConditionExpression: "#column = :fileFullPath",
            ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                "#column": "filePath"
            },
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":fileFullPath": BUCKET + "/" + FILE_KEY
            }
        };

        docClient.query(queryParams, function(err, data) {

            if (err) {
                console.log("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            } else {
                console.log("Query succeeded.");
                data.Items.forEach(function(item) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(item));
                });
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Are you using any framework for writing test? If so, please can you show your code?

Comment: @notionquest Yes, mocha.js and chai.js